# How to override keybinding in a control in wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have the following code which uses Microsoft's WPFToolkit AutoCompleteBox. I have tried adding an input binding inside it

```
xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"

<tk:AutoCompleteBox IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" FilterMode="Contains" ItemsSource="{Binding DistinctItemNames, Mode=OneWay}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        x:Name="searchBox" Width="300" Height="23" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
    <tk:AutoCompleteBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding ShowSelectedItemsCommand}"/>
    <tk:AutoCompleteBox.InputBindings>
</tk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

However, it doesn't work. I expect that the control itself handles the 'Enter' or 'Return' key so how can I override its default function?
I have also put that keybinding directly under the 'UserControl.InputBindings' and it also did not work. I hate to use Code Behind to handle the command logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event, either directly in the code-behind of the view:

```
private void AutoCompleteBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        AutoCompleteBox box = sender as AutoCompleteBox;
        dynamic viewModel = box.DataContext;
        viewModel.ShowSelectedItemsCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

...or by wrapping it in an attached behaviour: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF.

Neither approach breaks the MVVM pattern. In the first case you are just invoking the exact same view model command from the exact same view. But if you really "hate to use code-behind" for some strange reason, then create an attached behaviour.

Comment: Thanks . I don't actually have a problem with the code behind as long as code inside it is minimal. What I don't want to do here is to handle the ShowSelectedItems() code inside the code behind. I prefer it to remain in the viewmodel and your answer solved it. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at this post: [ReactiveCommand pass Command Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146590/reactivecommand-pass-command-parameter). 
It uses Reactivity to accomplish the same thing you want.

Then, you can process the key received via KeyCode, and check if it is the key you want.